# Overflow property not working in IE Edge and Firefox when using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

My code below works fine in Chrome and Safari but does not seem to work in **IE Edge** and **Firefox** (Not in IE11 either but that's out of the question).

If I don't use `subheader` and `nested-content` as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322163/overflow-property-not-working-in-ie-11) then it renders it properly in those browsers. But this dictates how my components need to be structure and I was hoping to avoid that.

Will this way of doing it work by doing some more things for Firefox and Edge or do I need to rethink the nesting?

**Edit:** My case is this: at the container level I know the max height (it is dynamically calculated and set in a "Popover" component). But I cannot set any specific max-height in the children since they are just the "content" of the Popover. And I don't want the entire `.container` to overflow but instead only the list `nested-content`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 140px;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.header {
  background: lightgray;
}
.subheader {
  background: lightblue;
}
.content {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
}
.content > div {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.nested-content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header without specific height. Always stays at top of .container, even if it is so long it uses up two lines.</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subheader">Subheader without specific height.</div>
    <div class="nested-content">
      <div>Item no 1 in long list</div>
      <div>Item no 2 in long list</div>
      <div>Item no 3 in long list</div>
      <div>Item no 4 in long list</div>
      <div>Item no 5 in long list</div>
      <div>Item no 6 in long list</div>
      <div>Item no 7 in long list</div>
      <div>Item no 8 in long list</div>
      <div>Item no 9 in long list</div>
      <div>Item no 10 in long list</div>
      <div>Item no 11 in long list</div>
      <div>Item no 12 in long list</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this plunker is the correct solution for your case
https://plnkr.co/edit/12N6yofXXeUoTrG6tUuZ?p=preview

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 140px;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.header {
  background: lightgray;
}
.subheader {
  background: lightblue;
}

.content {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
  overflow:auto;
}
.content > div {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.nested-content {
  overflow: auto;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only overflows the entire container. I only want overflowing on the list of items (`nested-content`)

Comment: then you need to set a max height for its parent

Comment: Sorry, good point! The question is missing an important requirement, but I've added it now.

Comment: I edited my answer please check the plunker above may it give you an idea to solve the problem

Comment: I don't want to be dependant on fixed heights and calc in the content. But actually, your first answer led me to the missing piece. On Firefox and Edge, I needed to put `overflow: auto` on the `.content` **as well**. When doing that, it works! If you change your answer to that i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's a bug in Firefox and, evidently, in Edge as well.

Please, refer to the solution already exposed on Stackoverflow: "[firefox overflow-y not working with nested flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28639686/877464)"