# css overflow auto is not working for IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Have a div with `position: static` and `overflow: auto`. when changing the resolution of the screen overflow is not working for x axis in IE11.

```
div{
 overflow: auto;
 position: static
}
```

Comment: It looks like this thread can help with your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322163/overflow-property-not-working-in-ie-11

Comment: You could refer to ASG's link. Or could you please share more detailed code like how is your div specifically designed? Maybe the related css code has affected this. And it will be better to help with you.