# IE11 overflow:hidden not working during transition

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I am using owl carousel spotlight with scale effect.

The `overflow:hidden` for the outer div is not working in IE11 during the scale transition

```css
.spotlight{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img{
  transition: all ease 2s;
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.active img{
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="spotlight">
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt=""></div>
<div class="item"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt=""></div>
<div class="item"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt=""></div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  autoplay: true,
  items: 1,
  margin:10,
  nav:true,
  animateOut: 'fadeOut'
  });
})

</script>
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jt2wLx6v/7/

Comment: I made several tests with your sample by modifying the CSS code but the issue persists in the IE browser. while searching I found that owl carousel has many issues with the IE browser which we can't fix using code. I suggest you create an issue on their GitHub page. https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen

Answer (score 0):

IE11 has a lot of issues and this is one of them. here is a link to an already answered similar question that could help you. Let me know

[Overflow property not working in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322163/overflow-property-not-working-in-ie-11)